# Zend GData YouTube API errors

Tags: zend-framework, youtube

Greetings,

Having quite a bit of difficulty with the YouTube API. I added the Zend Gdata folder to my include_path and all of the API tests run fine, but when I try to load the YouTube API Demo App, I get the following error:

```
Warning: include_once(Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tappess1/public_html/includes/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/tappess1/public_html/includes/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Warning: require_once(Zend/Exception.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tappess1/public_html/includes/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 98

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/tappess1/public_html/includes/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 98
```

The PHP include_path seems to be set correctly, the tests run.. the issue seems to be either in operations.php in the YouTube API's demo or in Loader.php. The default directory for Loader.php was simply `Zend/Loader.php`, I generally use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/dir';` due to listing restrictions on my host.

Any idea why this will not work? It occurs when I click on the Authenticate link within the demo.

Thanks

Comment: This is more of a programming question, and would be better suited to our sister site stackoverflow.com. It will be moved when it gains enough close votes.

Comment: Thanks, Sam... I was beginning to think that was the case. I'll swing over there, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Urgh, I had exactly the same errors. My solution was to totally scrap using the Zend GData API and use the REST interface. This way you're writing more code, but it's all under your control.